# Differencing two tables in a SQL database?

Tags: sql, sqlite

How can I compare two tables with unique keys and generate a difference set that can transform one table into the other?  For example, given tables A and B, identify:

- inserted rows:  The key appears in B, but not in A.
- deleted rows:  The key appears in A, but not in B.
- modified: The key appears in both tables, but with different values.
- unmodified:  the key appears in both tables, and the values are the same.

For example, given the data below, identify:

- a is modified, 1 --> 9
- b is deleted
- c is unmodified
- d is inserted

```
CREATE TABLE A AS SELECT 'a' AS key, 1 AS val
    UNION SELECT 'b', 2
    UNION SELECT 'c', 3;

CREATE TABLE b AS SELECT 'a' AS key, 9 AS val
    UNION SELECT 'c', 3
    UNION SELECT 'd', 4;

SELECT * FROM a ORDER BY KEY;
a,1
b,2
c,3

SELECT * FROM b ORDER BY KEY;
a,9
c,3
d,4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These queries will perform the specified operations.

- Modified Rows

```
select b.key, b.val from a left join b
    on a.key = b.key where a.val <> b.val;
a,9
```

- Deleted Rows

```
select key, val from a where key not in (select key from b);
b,2
```

- Unmodified Rows

```
select key, val from a intersect select key, val from b;
c,3
```

- Inserted Rows

```
select key, val from b where key not in (select key from a);
d,4
```

Note that if you have multiple columns in your key, you can specify them as `(`*key1*, *key2*, ...`)`, etc.  For example, if the tables had two key columns the Inserted query would be

```
select key1, key2, val from b
    where (key1, key2) not in (select key1, key2 from a);
```